# Find p such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{2017}}{n^p-(n-1)^p}=\frac{1}{2018}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I need to find $p$ natural number such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{2017}}{n^p-(n-1)^p}=\frac{1}{2018}$

I started with $a^n-b^n$ and I got $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{2017}}{n^{p-1}+n^{p-2}(n-1)+n^{p-3}(n-1)^2+...+(n-1)^{p-1}}$

How to continue?

Comment: you started wrong. do binomial expansion on $(n-1)^p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{n^{2017}}{n^p-(n-1)^p}=\frac{n^{2017}}{\binom{p}{1}n^{p-1}-\binom{p}{2}n^{p-2}+\dotsb }=\frac{n^{2017-p+1}}{\binom{p}{1}-\binom{p}{2}\frac{1}{n}+\dotsb }.$$
As $n \to \infty$, the terms with $\frac{1}{n^k} \to 0$. So you have to deal with $n^{2017-p+1}$ in the numerator and $\binom{p}{1}=p$ in the denominator. Can you have a positive power of $n$ in the numerator? so.....

Comment: Thank you for your answer!